# Tips on creating a C# WPF application to track my work hours

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to write a simple WPF application in C#. Coming from a primarily front-end web dev background, I'm sort of new to this, and I'd really like tips on where to start. :) I've searched the internet for resources, but haven't found anything yet which gives a more solid sense of direction in how I should approach the problem.

Basically, I'd like an application where I can click one button to "Check In" and save a timestamp, then another button to "Check Out" that saves another timestamp. I'd then like to be able to calculate how many total hours I've worked based on these timestamps.

Right now, I think the biggest problem I have is figuring out how/where to save the timestamp information. I've read stuff online on using a database, like SQLite, or something else called IsolatedStorage...

Any tips on how to tackle this would be super appreciated.

Comment: If you don't get very far, take a look at some of the solutions that are already out there: [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com), [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com).

Comment: This is not a very suitable question for this site, you can break down the problem into areas and see if there are individual solutions or ask questions about those individual problems, like "Where to store application data?". If you have absolutely no idea about WPF please see the introductory articles on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx).

Comment: Tip for the program itself: instead of having to manually click a button to check in or check out, it would be nicer if it could track the times you log in/log out of the computer, i.e. check-in = first login in day; check-out = last logout in day.

Comment: I've already tried looking at the intro articles on MSDN, but they don't give much guidance for beginners. I also posted this as a first question rather than breaking it down because I'm looking for a starting point; I don't even have enough experience or knowledge to figure out how many parts to break it down into. As of right now, I do know the main part I have problems with revolve around how and where to store data, which I already explained and specifically pointed out. I also don't want existing solutions; I'm using this a learning opportunity to teach myself something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in WPF, which I don't think is necessary (You can achieve the same thing with WinForms if it doesn't need to look so nice), you can use one of these classes:

1. `DateTime`
2. `StopWatch`

As for the gui, well this is simple enough. Just add two buttons to the window.

Finally for storage, if you can store the data on your HD it will be simple to save it.
Otherwise SQL is an option:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that if it's only for you, a very simple web app is the best, if you come from a web developer background.

I think that a sqlite file is a great idea, but for simplicity you can also consider an xml, a json file, or a simple .txt file.

Don't know if it was helpful, just my suggestion.

Comment: I thought about that too, but I also want to take this as an opportunity to learn something new. I'd really like to at least attempt to make a desktop app before resorting to a web app.

Thank you though!